# How do i code my css to output my html dropdown like the pictures below

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

How do modify my css to output my html dropdown menu like this before dropdown icon click

[image]

and like this

[image: ]]

after dropdown icon click 
i tried with these code:

```css
a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #555;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4C8FEC url(menu-icon.png) right;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

section {
  margin: 80px auto 40px;
  max-width: 980px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px
}


/*MEDIA QUERY*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    center: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  form.index-search-form {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  button[name="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  input.search-box {
    width: 250px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    padding: 2px 0;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
  <form action="search.php" method="post" class="index-search-form">
    <input name="search" type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="&#xf002;  What are you looking for?">
    <button name="submit" class="" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

but output this before dropdown icon is click

http://i63.tinypic.com/2dhct3q.jpg

and this after dropdown icon is click

[image]

what should i do big thanks for your time and impact in my soluction

Comment: What have you actually done?

Comment: How sorry i have to redit to question is posted wrong way

Comment: @Praveen Kumar i have just edited with my tried code looking at it do you have any idea or soluction to my problem?